# where to put JxBrowser license.jar for web start

Tags: jxbrowser

While searching the documentation for JxBrowser 6.3 for web start, I found https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013122-java-web-start There I can read that I have to sign the license.jar too.

But I can't find the entry in any jnlp file, where the license.jar has to be added. Or is this not necessary?

Comment: Which IDE you are using? Eclipse: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012870-jxbrowser-in-eclipse   For Intellij: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012869-jxbrowser-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Eclipse, but on the link I can't find any hint concerning web start!
It seems, that the license.jar has to be added to the jxbrowser.jnlp, where the jxbrowser-6.3.jar is added.

Comment: You need to include the license.jar file into your JWS application class path as well. Please note that you need to sign the license.jar file with your own valid signature. I recommend that you just extract the teamdev.licenses file from the license.jar file and put it into your application JAR file META-INF folder. As far as I know recent Java versions block JAR files with no *.class files inside, so the license.jar file might not be downloaded by JWS.